# What is the correct followup action after editing a question in the Triage review queue?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, triage

More than once I've come across a question in the [Triage review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review) which would be fine if it were more legible (sentence structure, punctuation, and especially code/error formatting related stuff). This is the kind of thing I'd select "Needs Community Edit" and not "Needs Author Edit" for, since the content is all there. But, if it's obvious how to fix the issues, sometimes I suggest the edit from outside the review queue (since for some reason editing from within the queue isn't one of the options there*).

*In the "First Questions" queue on [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour), there is an option to edit from within the queue. I am not sure why it's different here!

Assuming the edit has fixed all the issues, what is the correct next step? I'm not sure whether it would be better to select "Looks OK" (because it *will* look OK once the edit gets approved) or to still choose "Needs Community Edit" (because the edit might not get approved). I thought there might be guidance on this case [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/how-does-the-triage-review-queue-work/295674#295674), but the closest I could find was this quote from the **Needs Community Edit** subsection of the answer:

> "If you're sure that this question can be fixed through editing alone (see also Addendum: Bad Triage Review below) then hit Needs Community Edit. This keeps the post visible on the site and may add it to the Help & Improvement review queue, allowing other editors to find and improve it."

I'm not aware of there being a "Help and Improvement" review queue; is this something that used to exist, but no longer does? And the big issue is that the edit should have *already* fixed the issues, and if I understand correctly the pending edit must be processed anyway before another can be made. If the reviewer of the suggested edit finds additional issues, they would theoretically be addressing these from the ["Suggested Edits" review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review), so "Needs Community Edit" seems superfluous.

In the past I know I've chosen both possible actions at least once, but I wanted to ascertain the community's consensus before encountering that case again (until then, I'll just "Skip" after editing, since that's always a correct choice :D)

Comment: The Help & Improvement queue was removed (See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release?page=3&tab=scoredesc) The question goes to the First questions queue when you use "Needs Community Edit"